# Show that for $f(x)=x^2+x$ the mapping $f: A \rightarrow B$ is a bijection.

Tags: real-analysis

Here is a problem I am working on and a few parts are stumping me.

### Problem

Assume $A=[-\frac{1}{2},\infty), B=[-\frac{1}{4},\infty)$, where, for $a \in \mathbb{R}, [a,\infty)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}|x\geq a\}.$ Consider $f:A \rightarrow B$ defined by $f(x)=x^2+x, x\in A.$

1. Show that $f$ is indeed into $B$, i.e. show that if $x \in A$ then $f(x) \in B$.
2. Show that $f$ is one to one.
3. Show that $f$ maps onto $B$, i.e. show that for $y\in B$ there is $x \in A$ such that $f(x)=y$. For your choice of $x$, verify directly that $f(x)=y$.

### My attempt

1. I originally thought I would have to do something complicated to do this but at this point I am thinking it is fairly simple. Is it not true that $f:A \rightarrow B$ by definition implies that any element from $A$ is mapped to an element of $B$? If so I would imagine there is no need for an explanation other than citing the definition, but at the same time I am a bit hesitant as it seems like perhaps there is a way to verify this further.
2. I start by letting $x_1,x_2 \in [-\frac{1}{2},\infty)$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Then we can say that $x_1^2+x_1=x_2^2+x_2$. The goal is to show that $x_1=x_2$, but I am stuck on the algebra on how to show that. I tried factoring in multiple ways, such as
   $$x_1(x_1+1)=x_2(x_2+1)$$
   and
   $$(x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2)+x_1-x_2=0$$
   but nothing is jumping out at me to simplify to $x_1=x_2$.
3. Solving $y=x^2+x$ for $x$ we get $x=\pm \sqrt{y+\frac{1}{4}}-\frac{1}{2}.$ If we then let $y\in B$, we see that $y\geq-\frac{1}{4}$. If we apply our previous function of $y$ to our inequality we get that $\sqrt{y+\frac{1}{4}}-\frac{1}{2}\geq-\frac{1}{2}$, telling us that $x=\sqrt{y+\frac{1}{4}}-\frac{1}{2}\in A$. I verify this by showing if $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ then $y=-\frac{1}{4}$ and that if $y=-\frac{1}{4}$ then $x=-\frac{1}{2}$. Is this sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An elementary way.

(1) To prove $f$ is injective, let $x,y\in A$ such that $x \neq y$. If $x^{2}+x = y^{2}+y$, then $(x-y)(x+y) = y-x$, that is, we have $x+y = -1$. But this is impossible since $x\neq y$ and $x,y \geq -1/2$. Thus $f: A \to B$ is injective.

(2) To show $f$ is surjective, let $z \in B$. I claim that there is some $x \in A$ such that $f(x) = x^{2}+x = z$. But, since $x^{2}+x = z$ for some $x \in A$ if and only if $x = \frac{-1}{2} \pm \sqrt{1+4z}$, and since $z \geq -1/4$, so $x \geq -1/2$, and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

For part A,  they want you to confirm the range is accurate, that whatever you put in from $A$ will actually take you to $B$ and not to some other part of $\mathbb R$.   For that,  you can just use the derivative:  $f'(x)=2x+1$,  hence on $A$,  $f'(x)\ge 0$,  hence it is increasing, and the smallest value is at $f(\frac {-1} 2)=\frac {-1} {4}$

For B: Again use the derivative, $f'(x)>0$  for all but the starting point says that the function is strictly increasing, and strictly increasing functions are 1-1.

C:  Yes, that's pretty much it, you show that for any number $y\in B$ there is a preimage in $A$

Non calculus versions;  A:  This is the right half of the parabola,  the vertex is at $-\frac 1 2$,  so your range is the vertex to infinity (Same for C, honestly)

B:  This is the right half of a parabola,  so it passes the "horizontal line" test of a 1-1 function.

Comment: These answers make sense, but we have not yet talked about derivatives in class and I don't believe we are allowed to use them yet. Do you know if there is perhaps another way to do A and B?

Comment: Will add non calculus versions, though it seems silly since this is analysis :)

Comment: We are going through everything fairly formally and aren't supposed to use anything outside of the axioms and theorems we have talked about in class until we get to it, as we are trying to prove things as we go along, hence the lack of calculus. We will get to that soon I'm sure :)

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+x=y^2+y$ then $(x+\frac{1}{2})^2=(y+\frac{1}{2})^2$ thus $(x+\frac{1}{2})=(y+\frac{1}{2})$ that will give $x=y$ or $(x+\frac{1}{2})=-(y+\frac{1}{2})$ which gives $x+y=-1$ because of domain it gives $x=y=\dfrac{-1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to check that if you take something from $A$, you'll get in $B$, *a priori*, this application ends in $\mathbb{R}$, but you can narrow it down to $B$.
2. Good attempt, but it doesn't seem to work. Compute the derivative (it works).
3. I don't really understand what you are doing. Take $y \in B$. For $y\in B-\{\frac{1}{4}\}$ there is two real solutions to the equation $x^2 + x - y = 0$ (check it!). Only one of them is in $B$. 
   You've got to solve the previous equation, take the one in $B$, then apply $f$ to that solution and check if it works.
   Then Work on the case $y=\frac{1}{4}$ separately as you've done in your attempt.

EDIT : Oh alright I now understand what you've done in 3... Yea that's it, I just find the way you wrote it a bit weird.